# Remove tag and taxonomy from post by post id

Tags: php, wordpress

How can remove custom **taxonomy** by custom post type with **post id**...

`wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, 'sweet', 'post_tag' );`

Comment: Please explain me little more i m not clear this code. @TechnoDeviser

Comment: Thank you for reply @TechnoDeviser

Please explain me little me. this code not clear where i m use `sweet`

Comment: Custom post type shouldn't matter as you're using the ID. You should replace post_tag with the name of your custom taxonomy element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. hope this can solve your problem :

```
<?php wp_remove_object_terms( $id, $terms, $taxonomy ); ?>
```